# Sending two dependent transactions with different signers

Tags: transactions, confirmation

I have two transactions with different signers. First transaction changes the account state, and the second one requires that account state to be changed as a constraint (it's some boolean value). I use `confirmTransaction()` method to wait for the first transaction to end. When I specify `confirmed` commitment as a parameter in the method, the second transaction fails since the state is not changed yet. When I specify `finalized` commitment, second transactions passes but the conformations takes too long (about 10 seconds)

Is there any way to speed up this process without waiting so long for conformation of the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple instructions in thesame transaction.

```
instruction1 = TransactionInstruction(accounts, constants.PROGRAM_ID, instruction_data)
instruction 2 = TransactionInstruction(accounts2, constants.PROGRAM_ID, instruction_data2)

transaction = Transaction()

transaction.add(instruction1)
transaction.add(instruction2)

client.send_transaction(transaction, signer1, signer2)
```

that way it will execute in thesame transaction, but instruction 1 will execute before instruction 2, and you wouldn't have to wait for 10s or more.

**Note: This will fail if the second instruction needs to run atleast 1 slot later than instruction 1, or at a timestamp different from the timestamp of instruction 1**

Comment: Can you explain why slot and timestamp matters. What needs to be aware of when writing the instructions?

Comment: Single transaction with multiple signers solved our problem. @CyrialKamda-InglDAO please answer the question I ask above. Or give me a hint where should I learn those issues that you mentioned.

Comment: Slot and Timestamp only matter if you have a transaction that can't be executed earlier than a specific slot or time, for example, if Instruction 1 were  to include a timer, and said if instruction2 is called within the next 30 mins or 60 slots, then the instruction fails, Then Including both instructions in the transaction will always fail.